# Can I use Auslander-Buchsbaum formula for polynomial rings?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homology-cohomology

Let $R=k[x,y]$ be a polynomial ring over a field $k$ and set $T=R/\langle xy,y^2‎‎\rangle $‎. ‎Let $f:R\to T$ be the natural ring epimorphism‎. ‎Is $\operatorname{pd}_RT=2$?
we know that $\operatorname{depth} R=2$ and $\operatorname{depth}_R T=0$.

$R$ is not local. Can I use the Auslander-Buchsbaum formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Auslander-Buchsbaum formula is true also in the graded case and here T is a finitely generated graded R-module. For the proof in this case you may look at Corollary A.4.3 of the book "Monomial Ideals" by Herzog and Hibi.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.